# Not able to Display Image using AngularJS path from JSON

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

Here i like to explain my problem clearly.
Am not able to display image using from angularJS path from Json and Image stored in local folder

HTML

```
<div controller="canController">
<tr ng-repeat="can in canList">
    <td>{{can.can_name}}</td>
    <td><img ng-src="{{can.can_path}}" alt="{{can.can_name}}"></td>
</tr>
</div>
```

canController.js

```
$http.get('/auth/canUploadList').success(function(response){
            $scope.canList = response;
            console.log($scope.canList);
        });
```

JSON:

```
[
{
_id: "5672747ab0c1a0841314bf76",
can_path: "uploads/1450341498134-Bisleri.jpg",
can_name: "Hapserve",
__v: 0,
date: "2015-12-17T08:38:18.149Z"
},
{
_id: "56728c05a14c24701299fb52",
can_path: "uploads/1450347525373-Kinley.png",
can_name: "Kinley",
__v: 0,
date: "2015-12-17T10:18:45.397Z"
}
]
```

getting Output like this:
[image: output_image]

Help me to sort out this problem

**Updated:**

```
router.get('/canUploadList', function(req, res){
        Can.find(function(err, docs){
            res.json(docs);
        });
    });



router.post('/canUpload', upload.single('can_image'), function(req, res, next) {
        console.log(req.body);
        console.log(req.file);
        var newCan = Can();
        newCan.can_name = req.body.can_name;
        newCan.can_path = 'uploads/' + req.file.filename;
        console.log(newCan.can_path);
        newCan.save(function(err, docs){
            if(err)
                throw err;
            else
                res.redirect('/auth/canUpload');
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<td><img ng-show="{{can.can_path}}" alt="{{can.can_name}}"></td>
```

to

```
<td><img ng-src="{{can.can_path}}" alt="{{can.can_name}}"></td>
```

try this.
change `ng-show` to `ng-src`

Comment: can you try and check if image opens in browser. to crossverify its not broken

Comment: yeah not opening in browser

Comment: then some problem with data not code.. if it working with proper image do accept answer. thanks.

Comment: server code why? you see in console.log that you have put that values are  coming

Comment: where are those images ? is your backend and front end server same... do you have folder named uploads on your front end server root with those images ?

Comment: yeah i have folder called uploads

Comment: images with names mentioned above in that uploads folder ? did you put absolute path in browser right ?

Comment: yeah...every images which i upload is there in the folder